# Map Service Publishers

Tags: google-maps, maps

I am creating a mobile web-app and need a map publisher/provider.  I have gone through a couple of them such as:
- Google Maps
- Bing Maps
- Map Box
- OpenStreetMap

After reviewing the map publishers and their price plans, I am mostly interesting in free map publishers at this point.  However, on reviewing OpenStreetMap, they do not provide maps in a good detail for my country.  Can anyone suggest any other free map providers apart from OpenStreetMap?  I have found a couple of other ones, however they are all built on top of OpenStreetMap (such as MapBox which is commercial)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If by "free" you mean "free beer" instead of "free speech", I can recommend HERE Maps.
Its JS API is fairly good, and depending on your country, the details are awesome.